# Securing and Storing a URL into DB

Tags: php, database, url, mysqli

I'm trying to develop the best way to store a URL into a database, and make sure it has either http://www. or https://www., etc., correctly place infront of it. So if someone put in stackoverflow.com, it'd correct it to https://www.stackoverflow.com instead. That way when it echos out the url on the page and is clicked, I won't have to worry about the link breaking.

Also, the second part of this, I have tried to just straight up store a link inside a database, and sometimes it won't allow it when submitting via php/mysqli. I think it was a character or something like that, that wouldn't allow it to be stored. Should I encrypt the link and then decrypt it upon showing on the page?

I greatly appreciate the help, and none of the things I searched on google were helping, and trying to get a site for a charity done for an event for then.

Comment: 1. remove http:// or https:// before adding to db 2. After getting a row concat with http:// , this can be done by "http://" . $variable

Comment: for part 2 what data type you are using for storing url?

Comment: I had originally stored it as a varchar, but changed it after thinking in some cases more than 256 characters  would be needed, to a text field. I think the http:// might have been the issue. I'll try to see if a preg replace will work best for stripping the http: or https: before storing. will adding just http: for https: sites be ok for the url? It seems to correct itself when I tried doing it to google.

Comment: `varchar` is not suitable for storing urls u might never know how long url will be go with `mediumtext` , yes adding http is okay most of the site if u visit via http will work , some of them may enforce https like google and facebook does , but its a win win situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out.

```
$mylink = https://www.google.com
$stripped_http = preg_replace("(^https?://)", "", $mylink);
```